# Should I use a temporary table or a persistent table for staging and merging data in MSSQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table which needs to be populated with quite a few rows, on the order of millions per hour.

Right now I have an application developed in C# using the entity framework and it does not support bulk copying. I have previously developed a solution which uses bulk copying and it was a massive performance improvement.

I have been copying the data to a staging table and then merging the staging table with the production table, in order to resolve `UNIQUE` constraint conflicts.

Now my question today is, should I be using a temporary table as a variable inside the stored procedure and do all of the merging and conflict resolution there? In the current solution, we do the bulk copy and then invoke a stored procedure which merges and empties the table.

What kind of performance effects would it have to use the temporary table?

Is it considered a bad practice at all to use the temporary table? If so, why?

Are there alternatives in MSSQL 2012 that would be neat to use to solve this problem?

Comment: For clarification, are you using a temp table (`#tablename`) or a table variable (`@tablename`)? - it's a bit ambiguous with the way your question is currently worded.

Comment: I'm not using any temporary table. I was referring to the `#tablename` temporary table though. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should I be using a temporary table as a variable inside the stored
>   procedure and do all of the merging and conflict resolution there?

I think it's better use temp table to avoid problems with concurrent execution of the stored procedure, for different instances of the procedure can try to read and modify the same rows.

> What kind of performance effects would it have to use the temporary
>   table?

Temp tables (as well as table variables) are stored in `tempdb` so you can get a bottleneck there.

> Is it considered a bad practice at all to use the temporary table?

No. But using them without necessity you do extra write and read operations because first you read data by some query, write it into temp table and than read data one more time.

Answer (score 0):

temp tables are slower which is why i wouldn't use them if it can be avoided. The only reason why you might use tempTables is if several users are using that procedure. In that case it might be better.

Comment: What do you base "temp tables are slower" on? They have less logging and locking so will likely be faster.

Comment: @Martin Smith Its called experience. I had to solve a very similar problem. wehere gigabytes of data needed to be integrated. when i replaced the tmptables then there was a boost in performance. ,

Comment: Maybe on your particular instance `tempdb` wasn't configured correctly (e.g. may have had slower disk, more contention, auto growth settings incorrect) but you can't extrapolate a general rule that "temp tables are slower" from that.

Comment: Besides the creation time (less than 1 milisecond) temp tables are just as fast as permanent tables and often faster since tempdb has logging optimizations compared to normal databases.

Comment: @Martin Smith For very simple problems temp tables can be as fast. For more complex operations such as union etc he will find that temp tables have restrictions such as no foreign keys. This will make it slower. Temp table make a db design pretier it will not make it better.

Comment: er, what. Why would you want foreign keys in a staging table? They would make things slower as the FKs need to be validated.

Comment: @Martin Smith Er, well. If he simply wanted to import some data then he wouldn't use temp tables would he? He needs to evaluate the data.

Comment: To clarify, I do need the foreign keys in the staging table. The staging table is purely being used to enable bulk copying for periodic high volume insertion. But, the data going in should maintain valid relationships. It would be copied afterward, via a `CommitStaging` stored procedure or something.